# Plotting and merging plots

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

Let

```
 x=[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12];
 t=[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11];
```

Then

```
plot(t, x);
```

will produce a straight line as shown below:
[image]

Now suppose I am not given x and t instead x and t being decomposed into 4 different sections:

```
x1=[1 2 3];
x2=[4 5 6];
x3=[7 8 9];
x4=[10 11 12];

t1=[0 1 2];
t2=[3 4 5];
t3=[6 7 8];
t4=[9 10 11];
```

I have to plot x1, x2, x3 and x4 such that I again get the same plot as above. What do I do ?

If I try this :

```
plot(t1,x1, t2,x2,  t3,x3, t4,x4 )
```

Then I am NOT getting as expected:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can concatenate the vectors and then plot them. Like this:

```
t=[t1 t2 t3 t4];
x=[x1 x2 x3 x4];

plot(t,x);
```